# Fingering and Tips for the runs on Liszts Hungarian Rhapsody No.2

Tags: piano, fingering, rhapsody

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qukD.jpg

Hello, I've always had trouble finding fingerings especially for a fast run like this so I would like some guidance! This is actually one of the first times I've actually needed to play a run so Id like some tips on learning fast parts like this. Thanks,

Comment: What's the problem with the fingering? It's just a scale! But if you never bothered to practice scales, you just found out why you should have bothered...

Comment: @alephzero welcome somebodies first question with a tone of resentfulness and depreciation, I really wonder if this adds value to the community?

Comment: @user19146 If that's just a scale everything in the existing piano repetoire can be dismissed as just scales, and so all fingering problems could be answered with "you just don't practice scales". No. Just no.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

[image]

[Source on IMSLP](http://ks.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/f/f7/IMSLP169523-PMLP12453-Rapsodie_Hongroise_no.2-Liszt,Philipp.pdf)